# Alignment with Tailwind and React

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get two different visualizations to properly sit next to each other.

This is the current styling...

```
          <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row" >
            <div className="w-full md:w-2/3">
              <div className="text-center mt-4 flex justify-center items-center">
                <h1 className="text-blue-500 text-lg font-semibold mr-5">
                  {format(new Date(selectedDate), 'do, MMMM - yyyy')}{' '}
                </h1>
                {isLoading && <Loader />}
              </div>
              <div>
                <div className = "grid-cols-2 grid-flow-col" >
                  <div className = "grid-cols-1">
                    <h3 className="capitalize">Moodmap Daily Index</h3>
    
                      <Overview data={lineGraphData} timing={settingsData} />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <Expressions data={expressionsData} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style={{ height: 100, width: 1000 }}>
                <SubstanceDetails
                  fetchSubstances={fetchSubstances}
                  loading={loading}
                  data={data}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

For some reason when it renders, although I've made a bunch of changes, it comes out like this,

[image]

I want them to sit horizontally, with the bottom graph on the right hand side, ideally with the line graph a lot larger, taking up say 2/3. Unsure why this bug keeps happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a grid container by including the `grid` className in the element where you specify your grid columns:

```
<div className = "grid-cols-2 grid-flow-col" >
```

should become:

```
<div className = "grid grid-cols-2 grid-flow-col" >
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#grid

Note, to debug this you could have used the inspector to see that there was no grid container in your output.